# Problem to make strip() function work properly in the entire dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

the strip function is not properly working with one country in the data frame
"""

```
<Country  Energy Supply  Energy Supply per Capita  % Renewable
0           Afghanistan   3.210000e+08                      10.0    78.669280
1               Albania   1.020000e+08                      35.0   100.000000
2               Algeria   1.959000e+09                      51.0     0.551010
3        American Samoa            NaN                       NaN     0.641026
4               Andorra   9.000000e+06                     121.0    88.695650
5                Angola   6.420000e+08                      27.0    70.909090
6              Anguilla   2.000000e+06                     136.0     0.000000
7   Antigua and Barbuda   8.000000e+06                      84.0     0.000000
8             Argentina   3.378000e+09                      79.0    24.064520
9               Armenia   1.430000e+08                      48.0    28.236060
10                Aruba   1.200000e+07                     120.0    14.870690
11            Australia   5.386000e+09                     231.0    11.810810
12              Austria   1.391000e+09                     164.0    72.452820
13           Azerbaijan   5.670000e+08                      60.0     6.384345
14              Bahamas   4.500000e+07                     118.0     0.000000
```

> 

here is the code i apply to get rid of the outter spaces in each cell

```
Energy = pd.read_excel("assets/Energy Indicators.xls", header = 17, skipfooter = 38)
Energy.pop('Unnamed: 0')
Energy.pop('Unnamed: 1')
Energy.columns.values[0:4] =['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
Energy = Energy.replace('...', np.nan)
**Energy = Energy.replace('Iran ', 'Iran')**
**Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.strip()**
Energy['Energy Supply'] = Energy['Energy Supply']. multiply(1000000)
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace("\(.*\)","")
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace('\d+', "")
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].replace(["Republic of Korea", "United States of America", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region"], ["South Korea", "United States", "United Kingdom", "Hong Kong"])
**(Energy == 'Iran ').sum()**
```

```
**Country                     1**
Energy Supply               0
Energy Supply per Capita    0
% Renewable                 0
dtype: int64
```

However Iran keep having the space on its right size

I would like to get rid of Iran space either applying a function to the whole dataframe or by directly removing the space of Iran

Answer (score 0):

You might want to select the string columns and apply `str.strip`:

```
cols = Energy.select_dtypes('object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.strip())
```

Comment: I tried to apply it as follows

Comment: cols = Energy.select_dtypes('object').columns
Energy[cols] = Energy[cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.strip())   
But it did not work